# Arduino - To begin a timer when a button is pressed

Tags: arduino

I would like to start a timer once a button is pressed. The timer will light up an LED for five minutes. After the five minutes has expired I would like it to wait two minutes before registering another button press.

Comment: ok, so where do you think you should start?

Comment: What exactly are you asking us for? What do you need help with? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do this.
I will use the Delay command for a period of time whilst LED is on high
then after the period of time I will set LED to low
and so on and so forth.
I have all the code that I have used here.

```
const int LED2 = 12;
const int LED = 13;
const int BUTTON = 7;

int var = 0;

int val = 0;
int old_val = 0;
int state = 0;

void setup(){                               //telling the computer what the LED and the               button are
  pinMode (LED2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (BUTTON,INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  val = digitalRead(BUTTON);

  if ((val == HIGH) && (old_val == LOW)){    
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH); 
    delay(240000);                         //The period of time to wait before turning    on the LED2
    digitalWrite(LED2,HIGH);
    delay (1000);
    digitalWrite(LED2,LOW);
    delay (490000);
    var = 0;
    while(var < 10){                      //A while loop to flash the LED2 on and off
      digitalWrite(LED2,HIGH);
      delay (500);
      digitalWrite(LED2,LOW);
      delay (500);
      var++;
    }
    digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
    delay(120000);                        //A two minute delay before the button can be pressed again
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in example program "Blink without Delay" and combine it with "Button". Both programs are available as tutorials at http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage Try to avoid the delay() function because it wastes the processors time and has timing inaccuracies if there are interrupts.